# Matrix Norm SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $||A||_1=tr((A^* A)^{1/2})$ In my linear algebra book, we have the following relations

For arbitrary unitary matrices U and V let $||UAV^*||_1=||A||_1$, $||A||_1=\sigma_1+...+\sigma_k$ and $||A||_1=||A^*||_1$

Could you explain me why these relations hold?

Comment: Note how the spacing around the addition symbols gets messed up if you use `...` instead of one of the predefined commands, `\ldots` or `\dotso` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, note that $(UAV^*)^*(UAV) = V A^* U^* U A V^* = VA*A V^*$.  Now $(A^* A)^{1/2}$ is by definition the positive semidefinite square root of $A^* A$.  If this is 
$P$, then $VPV^*$ is also positive semidefinite and $(VPV^*)^2 = VP^2V^* = VA^*AV^*$, so
$VPV^* = (VA^*AV^*)^{1/2}$.  Finally, $\text{tr}(VPV^*) = \text{tr}(PV^*V) = \text{tr}(P)$ since $\text{tr}(CD) = \text{tr}(DC)$ for any  matrices $C,D$ such that both $CD$ and $DC$ exist.

$\|A\|_1 = \text{tr}(P)$ is the sum of the eigenvalues of $P$, but the nonzero eigenvalues of $P$ are the singular values of $A$.

$\|A\|_1 = \|A^*\|_1$ because $AA^*$ and $A^*A$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues.